# How to place an item accurately in a css grid in a specific row

Tags: html, css

I have an issue, or probably missed something in my css grid.

I am trying to position my text in a cell of the grid, however when I view the page, the text is placed outside the boundaries. I specified the height of the row, but it also is being set up automatically. Here is my code:

```css
    
    body {
        font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    }
    
    .container {
        width: 70%;
        margin:auto;
    }
    
    .grid{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-auto-rows: auto auto 50px auto auto;
    }
    
    .item {
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .navigation {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        text-align: right;
        vertical-align: center;
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 4;
    }
    
    .image {
        border: 1px solid black;
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end:4;
        grid-row-start: 2;
        grid-row-end: 5;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dolor {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row-start: 3;
        grid-row-end:4;
        align-self: center;
        text-align: right;
        border-bottom: 10px solid black;
        border-top: 10px solid black;
        border-right: 10px solid black;
        z-index: 2;
    
    }
    
    footer{
        background-color: black;
        color:white;
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 4;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: black;
    }

    li {
      float: left;
    }

    li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover {
      background-color: #111;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>lorem</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    

<div class="container"> 
<div class="grid">
  <div class="navigation">

     <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="item image"><img src="images/image1.jpg" alt=""></div>
 
<div class="item dolor"><h1>VA</h1><br><h1>RVCA</h1></div>
    
<footer class="item">footer</footer>

</div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

An image of the result:
[image: the rectangle to the left should be on the lines 3 and 4]

The expected result is to have the rectangle to the left align with line 3 and 4 in the row.

Edit: By looking into firefox grid, it seems the rows are defaulting to auto instead of taking into account the 50px. Is there a reason the 50px is being bypassed?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured it out, by removing the

```
align-self: center;
```

and adjusting the center row to have a height of 200px.

Still I don't think it is the best approach so if anyone ahs a better one, by using only the grid, it would be amazing!